# Why a charge moving generates magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, magnetic-fields

I don't have any illustrations of this, but is there any interpretation from quantum field theory, typically to counter why a moving charge generates a magnetic field, i.e. where does the magnetic field come from only while the charged particle in under motion? If it depends on the spin of the electron, why does the spin cause it to generate a magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

Why moving charges create a magnetic field around them is explained by the electrodynamics of the charged particle by switching frames of reference relativistic effects create the magnetic field which is just an electric field from the frame of reference in which the charged particle is at rest.

The spin of a subatomic particle is an intrinsic property of a subatomic particle which makes the subatomic particle behave like a tiny magnetic regardless of which frame of reference you see the particle.